# NgOnInit seems to be triggered before Input() receive data

Tags: angular, typescript, input, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying, as a personal challenge, to create a website where you can see a list of League Of Legends champions, and click on their icons to get more details.

However, the details of my champions (images specifically), seems to display one click late.

[image: Here, I clicked on the image of Kaisa, but the image of the previous champ is displaying]
Here, I clicked on the image of `Kaisa`, but the image of the previous champ is displaying

Here is how I get my datas.

**PARENT TS**

```
export class ChampionListComponent implements OnInit {

  public displayPopup = false;
  public selectedChamp: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private store: Store<LolState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedChamp = this.store.pipe(select(selectChampDetails));
  }

  selectChamp(name) {
    this.displayPopup = true;
    this.store.dispatch(new GetChampionsDetails(name));
  }
```

**PARENT HTML**

```
<ul class="champion_list">
  <li (click)="selectChamp(champion.key)">
    ...List of champions
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-container *ngIf="displayPopup">
  <app-champion-details *ngIf="selectedChamp | async as champ" [selectedChamp]="champ"></app-champion-details>
</ng-container>
```

**CHILD TS**

```
export class ChampionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() selectedChamp: any;
  public skins: Array<{path: string}>;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.selectedChamp.skins) {
      this.skins = this.selectedChamp.skins.map(skin => {
        return {path: 'LINK'}
      })
    }
  }
```

**CHILD HTML**

```
<section *ngIf="selectedChamp as Champ" class="container">
    <carousel cellWidth="100%" cellToShow="1" [loop]="true" [images]="skins"></carousel>
    <div class="champ_infos">
        <h2>{{Champ.id | titlecase}}</h2>
        <h3>{{Champ.title | titlecase}}</h3>
        <article>
            {{Champ.lore}}
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm getting the infos from my service, which is called by an effect, that dispatch actions, storing data in my state. The infos are well stored in my state, if I try to console.log `selectChamp` in the parent, it display the good information, no problem here.

It seems that Angular is trying to perform the `map` before the input received the information?

Edit: I replace `*ngIf="selectedChamp as Champ"` by `*ngIf="skins"` in my child, so the content doesn't show unless it's totally loaded, you can see the result in my gif.

[image]

(I removed some code that isn't really relevant for my problem, if there are some typos / unknown variables, please ignore it, as it's not the source of my problem)

Comment: Have a look at my answer to understand the real issue behind the scenes and you also might like my approach to make things easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use inputs for a child component, the value is available in OnChanges life cycle.
So you can try this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
if(changes && this.selectedChamp && this.selectedChamp.skins){
  this.skins = this.selectedChamp.skins.map(skin => {
        return {path: 'LINK'}
      })
    }
 }
```

in this life cycle every time the value updates in the parent, you can get it in child component.

Comment: Yea it works /o/
Still got a small problem tho', the old image is still there before the new image, for something like 0.2seconds. We can see, if I add a console.log() in `ngOnChanges`, that it seems to be called twice at each click (ex in gif below), any idea why it's hapenning ?

https://giphy.com/gifs/BcUHGsVKFAf9SPtKlN

Comment: I dont know if the problem is related to this or not, but you are changing displayPopup value before observable returns, it would be better if you subscribe the value from observable comes and when it received then change the displayPopup  to true.

Comment: I don't really like subscribing to an observable with something else than Async, my work taught me it was a bad practice, so i'm trying to avoid it as much as possible.
That <div> is only here for the black background anyway, doesn't really matter if it appears few seconds before my component, does it ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="displayPopup">
  <app-champion-details *ngIf="selectedChamp | async as champ" [selectedChamp]="champ"></app-champion-details>
</ng-container>
```

When the `displayPopup` becomes true you you are already showing the `champion-details` because `selectedChamp` Observable already has a value, if this is a second time when you are opening the details component. The new value arrives asynchronously later in time, but component has already initialized, thus your child component's `ngOnInit` has been fulfilled and it's showing the old state.

I suggest you to take a bit different approach. When you are closing the details component clear out the `selectedChamp` in the store. That way you don't even need the `ng-container` and you can simply rely only on the `*ngIf="selectedChamp | async as champ"` to display the details component.

```
  <app-champion-details *ngIf="selectedChamp | async as champ" [selectedChamp]="champ"></app-champion-details>
```

So you would do something like this inside the `closeChampionDetails` method:

```
public closeChampionDetails() {
  this.store.dispatch(new ClearSelectedChampion());
}
```

Comment: That's a very good approach ! I did as you said, your solution alone doesn't fix my problem, but  if I add it to the solution of Saghi Shiri, it fix my problem of changes being detected twice !
It's still way cleaner so I'm keeping it, thanks for the explanation !

Comment: Btw good luck on the project, I really like your idea. It's a very good portfolio project, put this on the github and share the link, it's very cool. Keep working on it

Comment: That's exactly the idea, having something to add to my portfolio :)
Thanks for the kind words !

Comment: Keep in touch if you want I can help with finding proper Angular resources and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In the child component, you must prevent calling the input `selectedChamp` before the data passed to it, so you can do something like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.selectedChamp && this.selectedChamp.skins) {
      this.skins = this.selectedChamp.skins.map(skin => {
        return {path: 'LINK'}
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything... I edited my question to add a gif and a console.log so the problem is clearer.